# GCP - How to serve multiple applications on a load balancer using Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to setting up a load balance on kubernetes on GCP and got stucked now.
So I was following this tutorial ([Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer)) but I can't get past **Step 6: (Optional) Serve multiple applications on a load balancer**

I am using a node simple app that only prints a name from a config map.
After following every step my paths can not be found (404).

This is my deployment example (both my services uses "the same" deployment, only changing names and image):

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nodetestfoo
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nodetestfoo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nodetestfoo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/e3-dev-227917/nodetestfoo:v4
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: nodetestfoo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3333
          protocol: TCP
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: env-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodetestfoo
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3333
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3333
  selector:
    run: nodetestfoo
  type: NodePort
```

This is my ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /test
        backend:
          serviceName: nodetest
          servicePort: 3333
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: nodetestfoo
          servicePort: 3333
```

My kubectl describe ingress output:
[image]

The response of a request using a path
[image]

The response of a request without a path (this default back-end really does not exists, so I believe it's the expected behavior)
[image]

What should I do to make it work? I'm kinda lost here. (obviously I'm new to cloud, in the beginning of my studies)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, though you may be curious to look into the ingress-nginx project.  https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx

Comment: The 404 seems to indicate the ingress is working properly.  Confirm your image is working properly by hitting the internal endpoint from another pod.  Try, `kubectl exec <from-pod-name> -c nodetestfoo -- curl 10.12.2.20:3333/ -O -`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out the [ingress-nginx project](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) brought up by [Rexovas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10158863/rexovas) on the comments really helped me out! 
I will have to take more time to read and understand the project, but on a quick test I got it working fine!

I had to add it to my kubernetes and add the following annotations to my ingress:

```
annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

now I can access my different paths without a problem! :D

Currently I have no idea how reliable this solution really is.Just feels wierd having to use an "third-part" project to make it work

I'll be updating this post if any problem comes up

Answer (score 2):

Let me tell you what you did. You got a functional configuration, but didn't give it enough time to deploy the load balancer. It usually takes about 5 minutes to have a functional `http` load balancer. But you probably got anxious, and never let it to get fully configured. So, just get back to your original `Ingress`, create it, and wait. after like 5 minutes, curl it.

You are saying "I had to add this annotation...". By adding that annotation, you switched to a different Ingress Controller (which you had to install previously). Nginx Ingress Controller takes milliseconds to get ready, as is just has to update nginx server config file. Also the traffic goes through a `tcp` load balancer, which gets ready very quick too, to the Ingress Controller, which is a pod. So here you have a load balancer that gets ready in about 30 seconds, therefor it seems that it works, while the other one doesn't.

Now, I am telling this because you seem to be a little confused about what happened,  not because I'm advising getting back to GKE Ingress Controller. You still might want to stick to nginx Ingress Controller. It is reliable. I personally like it more then GKE, for several reasons. Or you might end up with any other. There are tens of Ingress Controllers now out there.

Comment: Oh, thank you for this explanation!
Oddly, I believe that I have waited more than 5 minutes at some point, but really not sure lol
Will probably be trying to use GKE controller again just to see it working

Comment: if you did wait long enough, then it's probably a legit 404. Do you have anything serving on `/test` or `/foo`? Meaning do you have a `/test/index.html` and `/foo/index.html`? If you do, try setting `/test/` and `/foo/`, although this is less likely to be the reason.

Comment: well, I had a service in each of them. The only thing the services did was return NAME and SURNAME variables that were in my configMap. I 've changed nothing in the services or their deployments to make it work with nginx controller

Comment: also tried to use the paths like /test/* or /test/ but no luck

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_6_optional_serve_multiple_applications_on_a_load_balancer) modify the ingress like following

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /test/*
        backend:
          serviceName: nodetest
          servicePort: 3333
      - path: /foo/*
        backend:
          serviceName: nodetestfoo
          servicePort: 3333
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually tried like this the first time but no luck :/ 
Anyhow, it's now working with [ingress-nginx project](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) :D

Just feels wierd having to use an "third-part" project to make it work